# How would I query the most recent, nearby Geopoints in a Firestore database?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would I get the most recent documents in Firestore, in a geolocation radius, sorted by time?

I have a solution to get all documents in a Firestore database that are within a specified geolocation radius.

I need these ordered by time. As you would imagine, in a place like Los Angeles, there could be 10,000 nearby posts, and my current solution just doesn't scale.

Here is my Firestore query in SWIFT 4:

```
var query = docRef.whereField("geo", isGreaterThan: lesserGeopoint).whereField("geo", isLessThan: greaterGeopoint)
```

This is good enough to get the closest posts to me. So then, once I have all the closest posts, I parse them and put them in an array, and sort the array as follows:

```
self.posts.sort(by: { $0.time > $1.time })
```

This works, however, I scale-tested with dummy data, and here are the results:

```
(N = amount of posts that are queried and loaded)

N               LOAD TIME (average)
-----------------------------------
0               303 ms
1               323 ms
100             393 ms
500             637 ms
1000            1011 ms (1 second)
5000            10439 ms (10.4 seconds)
```

Anything beyond 1,000 nearby posts just isn't practical. I also can't limit the query to 1000 documents, because it's not sorted by time on the Firestore server, so it would just take 1000 random documents that are nearby, and sort those by time. But there may be a more recent post that didn't make the cut in that batch.

How do I find a solution to get most recent, nearby posts, and limit the query so that my app can scale.

Comment: heard of GeoFire? Sounds like a use case for realtime db?

Comment: @RonRoyston I've used GeoFire multiple times. My question is asking for a solution for Firestore, not realtime db. Also, I'm not entirely sure you read the question. Geofire is strictly for geoqueries and does not support ordering and limiting by timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by ordering with your time field and setting a limit on the number of documents returned.

The first `.whereField` must contain the first `orderBy` field (which in your case is `time`). After your geo query parameters, order by the time field, then set a `limit` of (for example) 10, to get the top 10 results.

`query = docRef.whereField("time", isGreaterThan: 0).whereField("geo", isGreaterThan: lesserGeopoint).whereField("geo", isLessThan: greaterGeopoint).order(by: "time").limit(to:10)`

If you are storing the time as a Cloud Firestore native timestamp (ISO8601), then you'll need to use `whereField("time", isGreaterThan: "")`

### Update

This particular solution doesn't work, because you cannot perform range queries on 2 separate fields as decribed in,  [Simple and Compound Queries - Query Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

Comment: The thing is, for whatever reason, Firebase doesn't let us call orderBy on a field that isn't the one we ran a comparison on. For example, since I ran comparisons on "geo" field, I cannot order it by time. Very frustrating, I know

Comment: That's why you have add a .whereField for the time field at the beginning of your query. It doesn't need to filter anything. It just has to return all documents, hence >0 or >""

Comment: JUST noticed that, thank you so much. You're a genius for this.

Comment: `'InvalidQueryException', reason: 'Invalid Query. All where filters with an inequality (lessThan, lessThanOrEqual, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'timestamp' and 'geo''` a new error. I guess all the inequality WHERE clauses need to be on the same field.

Comment: The documentation simply states,
> However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field.
Can you add your new query, either in the comments or as an update at the end of your original question, please?

Comment: Okay.  I've checked the documentation.  In the [Simple and Compound Queries - Query Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) section, it does state that you cannot carry our range queries on more than one field.  Apologies for my incorrect answer

Comment: I've also built and tested your use case and received the same error `Error: Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties: [geo, timestamp]`.  I've updated my answer to reflect that it doesn't work.  If I can, I'll flag this with the Firebase team to see if they have any ideas

Comment: I've been giving this a lot of thought.  If you use the [Map of Values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values) solution to add a `location` object, containing the city (key) and timestamp (value), you could fetch all of the documents for a city ordered by timestamp.  Then you can filter by a more precise geo-point.  Not ideal, I know.  Alternatively, if your geo points are fixed, you could use Cloud Functions to write the data to something like BigQuery and then request it from there.

Comment: @JasonBerryman I thought something similar for our app: to add something like "cityId" or "stateId" to the items and then query by that. Very dirty stuff. For the moment we hope Google comes out with geoqueries and they can be combined with inequality filter, because it is some 'standard' querying style for apps imo.